# Docker machine users has no access to files on host

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, docker, debian

I have problem with setting up my docker environment on remote machine.

I prepared local docker machines. Problem is with nginx + php-fpm.

Nginx act as nginx user, php-fpm act as www-data user. Files on host machine (application files) are owned by user1. chmods are default for symfony2 application.

When I access my webserver it returns 404 error or just simple "file not found".

For a while exact same configuration works on my local Ubuntu 16.04, but fails on Debian Jessie on server. Right now it doesn't work on both. I tried everything, asked on sysops groups and googled for hours. Do you hve any idea?

Here is my vhost configuration

```
server {
  listen      80;
  server_name dev.xxxxx.co xxxxx.dev;
  root        /usr/share/www/co.xxxxx.dev/web;
  index       app_dev.php;

  client_max_body_size 100M;
  fastcgi_read_timeout 1800;

  location / {
    # try to serve file directly, fallback to app.php
    try_files $uri $uri/ /app.php$is_args$args;
  }

  location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
    expires       max;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log    off;
  }

  location ~ ^/(app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    # When you are using symlinks to link the document root to the
    # current version of your application, you should pass the real
    # application path instead of the path to the symlink to PHP
    # FPM.
    # Otherwise, PHP's OPcache may not properly detect changes to
    # your PHP files (see https://github.com/zendtech/ZendOptimizerPlus/issues/126
    # for more information).
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
  }

  location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    # When you are using symlinks to link the document root to the
    # current version of your application, you should pass the real
    # application path instead of the path to the symlink to PHP
    # FPM.
    # Otherwise, PHP's OPcache may not properly detect changes to
    # your PHP files (see https://github.com/zendtech/ZendOptimizerPlus/issues/126
    # for more information).
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
    # Prevents URIs that include the front controller. This will 404:
    # http://domain.tld/app.php/some-path
    # Remove the internal directive to allow URIs like this
    internal;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    return 404;
  }
}
```

nginx configuration

```
user              root;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

And my docker compose

```
version: '2'
services:
    nginx:
        image: nginx
        ports:
            - 8082:80
        volumes:
            - /home/konrad/Workspace:/usr/share/www:ro
            - ./conf/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
            - ./sites:/etc/nginx/conf.d:ro

    php-fpm:
        image: php:fpm
        ports:
            - 9000:9000
        volumes:
            - /home/konrad/Workspace:/usr/share/www
            - ./conf/www.conf:/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
            - ./conf/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/90-php.ini:ro
```

On remote server files are accesible, visible as property of 1001:1001